# How to authorize users (oAuth 2.0) on Facebook from a Java Desktop App?

Tags: java, facebook, oauth

I am writing a Facebook desktop app in Java that will authorize several users in succession (each in person typing in their credentials on my machine then logging out) and then use their profile ID and access_token to do some stuff with their statuses/picture etc.

From what I understand, the user must use a browser to authorize my app to use their info and then it will send the browser to a redirect URI: `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html? code=their_access_token`

How can I use the desktop app to launch a browser?  (If that is what I need to do, Mac specific is ok)

Then, how can I get that code back into my desktop app?

Some solutions I have tried are:

- Use javascript to find the `access_token` and write it to a file, that the java app can read
- Write a simple java web browser that pops up using swing elements

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html? code=their_access_token

from above -- code=their_access_token  --  this is not the access token. You should pass this code with your app secret with another url to get the access token.

I tried like you a lot. I was using javafx and there I had a webview and I did it. May be you should find some things in java which can help you in embedding a browser with your application.